# Allow redirects in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

This is my middleware:

```
from scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent import UserAgentMiddleware
from scrapy.exceptions import IgnoreRequest
from scrapy import log

class FilterURLs(object):
    def process_response(self,request, response, spider):
        if response.status == 301 :
            return response
        else:
            headers = ['text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'text/html;charset=UTF-8', 'text/html;charset=utf-8','text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1','application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8']
            log.msg("In Middleware " + repr(response.headers['Content-Type']), level=log.INFO)
            for header in headers:
                if response.headers['Content-Type'] != header:
                    raise IgnoreRequest()
                else:
                    return response
```

My error:

```
2014-01-09 13:08:56+0530 [crawler] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET  http://www.altria.com/Pages/default.aspx> from <GET http://www.altria.com>
2014-01-09 13:08:58+0530 [scrapy] INFO: In Middleware 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
2014-01-09 13:08:58+0530 [crawler] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.altria.com/Pages/default.aspx>
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

My scraper stops with the error. Is it not able to scrape redirected links?
Is it because it's not able to get content type of redirected link?

Comment: What's the traceback?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/aCkFX7BS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**:

After a second look, I can't reproduce your error using Scrapy 0.20.

The middleware:

```
from scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent import UserAgentMiddleware
from scrapy.exceptions import IgnoreRequest
from scrapy import log


class FilterURLs(object):
    def process_response(self,request, response, spider):
        if response.status == 301 :
            return response
        else:
            headers = ['text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'text/html;charset=UTF-8', 'text/html;charset=utf-8','text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1','application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8']
            log.msg("In Middleware " + repr(response.headers['Content-Type']), level=log.INFO)
            for header in headers:
                if response.headers['Content-Type'] != header:
                    log.msg("Ignoring response %r" % request)
                    raise IgnoreRequest()
                else:
                    return response
```

The spider:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'filtertest'
    start_urls = ['http://www.altria.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        self.log(response.url)
```

The settings:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'mytest.dlmw.FilterURLs': 1,
}
```

The output of `scrapy crawl filtertest`:

```
2014-01-10 10:05:27-0400 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.20.0 started (bot: pipetest)
2014-01-10 10:05:27-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto, django
2014-01-10 10:05:27-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'pipetest.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['pipetest.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'pipetest'}
2014-01-10 10:05:27-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2014-01-10 10:05:27-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: FilterURLs, HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpProxyMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2014-01-10 10:05:27-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2014-01-10 10:05:27-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: MyPipeline
2014-01-10 10:05:27-0400 [filtertest] INFO: Spider opened
2014-01-10 10:05:27-0400 [filtertest] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-01-10 10:05:27-0400 [filtertest] DEBUG: [MyPipeline] Initializing resources for filtertest
2014-01-10 10:05:27-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2014-01-10 10:05:27-0400 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2014-01-10 10:05:28-0400 [filtertest] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.altria.com/Pages/default.aspx> from <GET http://www.altria.com>
2014-01-10 10:05:28-0400 [scrapy] INFO: In Middleware 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
2014-01-10 10:05:28-0400 [scrapy] INFO: Ignoring response <GET http://www.altria.com/Pages/default.aspx>
2014-01-10 10:05:28-0400 [filtertest] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2014-01-10 10:05:28-0400 [filtertest] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 458,
     'downloader/request_count': 2,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 21358,
     'downloader/response_count': 2,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
     'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 10, 14, 5, 28, 452610),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 8,
     'log_count/INFO': 5,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 10, 14, 5, 27, 748879)}
2014-01-10 10:05:28-0400 [filtertest] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

*Previous answer*: Try this

```
        allowed_headers = ['text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'text/html;charset=UTF-8', 'text/html;charset=utf-8','text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1','application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8']
        log.msg("In Middleware " + repr(response.headers['Content-Type']), level=log.INFO)
        if response.headers['Content-Type'] in allowed_headers:
            return response
```

Comment: What about the redirects then? Because when it encounters a redirect it is not able to check for redirected url's header.

Comment: @wannaC I can't reproduce your error. See the updated answer. Are your settings correct?

Comment: @WannaC Also looks like your are using python 2.6. From 0.20 Scrapy requires python 2.7. You may want to update your python/twisted/scrapy installation.

Comment: I am usinng 0.18.4. I will change it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience in scrapy but your stack trace shows that you raised IgnoreRequest() as you explicitly did. If you only want to raise the exception on incompatible headers then replace your for loop

```
for header in headers:
    if response.headers['Content-Type'] != header:
        raise IgnoreRequest()
    else:
        return response
```

with

```
if not response.headers['Content-Type'] in headers:
    raise IgnoreRequest()
else:
    return response
```